# What is css in Android chrome "simplified view" aka reading mode?

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

What is css in Android chrome browser "simplified view" aka reading mode?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the CSS:

```css
:root{--google-blue-700: 25, 103, 210;--google-brown-900: 62, 39, 35;--google-purple-700: 132, 48, 206;--google-yellow-50: 254, 247, 224;--google-yellow-100: 254, 239, 195}*, *::after, *::before{box-sizing: border-box} blockquote, body, caption, dd, dl, fieldset, figure, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, hr, legend, ol, p, pre, ul, table, td, th{margin: 0;padding: 0;word-wrap: break-word} sub, sup{font-size: 75%;line-height: 0;position: relative;vertical-align: baseline}sup{top: -0.5em}sub{bottom: -0.25em} table{border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;display: block;overflow-x: auto}td, th{padding: 0.5rem} html{ font-size: 14px}body{-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;display: flex;flex-direction: column;line-height: 1.714;margin: 0 auto;min-height: 100vh;overflow-x: hidden;text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;transition-duration: 500ms;transition-property: color, background-color;transition-timing-function: ease} .light{background-color: #FAFAFA;color: #424242}.dark{background-color: #212121;color: #E0E0E0}.sepia{background-color: rgb(var(--google-yellow-50));color: rgb(var(--google-brown-900))}.light a:link{color: rgb(85, 85, 255)}.sepia a:link{color: rgb(var(--google-blue-700))}.dark a:link{color: rgb(136, 136, 255)}.light a:visited{color: rgb(144, 34, 144)}.sepia a:visited{color: rgb(var(--google-purple-700))}.dark a:visited{color: rgb(216, 114, 216)}.light code, .light pre{background-color: #EEE;border-color: #AAA}.sepia code, .sepia pre{background-color: rgb(var(--google-yellow-100));border-color: rgba(var(--google-brown-900), 0.5)}.dark code, .dark pre{background-color: #333;border-color: #555}.light tbody tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #EEE}.light th, .light td{border-left: 1px solid #AAA}.sepia tbody tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: rgb(217, 196, 175)}.sepia th, .sepia td{border-left: 1px solid rgb(147, 125, 102)}.dark tbody tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #333}.dark th, .dark td{border-left: 1px solid #555} #content-wrap th:first-child{border-left: none}#content-wrap td:first-child{border-left: none} .serif{font-family: serif}.sans-serif{font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif}.monospace{font-family: monospace} blockquote, caption, code, dd, dl, fieldset, figure, form, hr, legend, ol, p, pre, q, table, td, th, ul{margin-bottom: 1.143rem}h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{line-height: 1.417;margin: 1em 0} #loading-indicator{padding-bottom: 2em;width: 100%}#loading-indicator > img, #loading-indicator > svg{display: block;height: 2.5em;margin: auto;width: 2.5em} video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button{display: none}#content{margin: 24px 16px 24px 16px}#main-content{flex: 1 1 auto;margin: 0 auto;max-width: 35em;width: 100%}#article-header{margin-top: 24px;width: 100%}#title-holder{font-size: 1.714rem;line-height: 1.417;margin: 0 16px}blockquote{border-left: 4px solid #888;padding-left: 1em}cite{font-style: italic;opacity: .8}hr{border-style: solid;height: 1px 0 0 0;opacity: .5;width: 75%}q{display: block;font-style: italic;font-weight: 600;opacity: .8}embed, img, object, video{max-width: 100%} img{display: block;height: auto;margin: 0.6rem auto 0.4rem auto} embed+[class*='caption'], figcaption, img+[class*='caption'], object+[class*='caption'], video+[class*='caption']{display: table;font-size: 0.857rem;line-height: 1.667;margin-bottom: 1rem;opacity: .8}ol, ul{margin-left: 1.296rem}code, pre{border: 1px solid;border-radius: 2px}pre code{border: none}pre{line-height: 1.642;padding: .5em;white-space: pre-wrap}body .hidden{display: none}.clear{clear: both} .youtubeContainer{height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.25%;position: relative;width: 100%}.youtubeIframe{height: 100%;left: 0;position: absolute;top: 0;width: 100%}.desktop-only{display: none}
```